# Justify text and break words CSS rules is not working together. How to make a text justified and break words when its length is bigger than container?

Tags: css

I am trying to make a text justified (`textAlign: 'justify'`) using spaces (`textJustify: 'inter-word'`) and, when a big word appear, break to a new line (`wordBreak: 'break-all'`) using CSS.

This is the CSS applied to a text:

```
text: {
    textAlign: 'justify',
    textJustify: 'inter-word',
    wordBreak: 'break-all',
},
```

But I am not getting my purpose, instad of justify text content and break a word only when his length is bigger than div width, the text is being justified and breaking in the middle of the words.

Here is an example:

[image: Example 1]

As you can see, text is justified but words are breaked (`Comerç`, `la`, ...)

Do you know how can I achieve my purpose? Which CSS rules are correct?

Thank you.

---

UPDATE 1

I have tried, as @Awais suggest, use `wordBreak: 'break-word'`, but the justified looks bad.

The result is:

[image: Example 2]

Comment: Its due to `break-all`, Did you try setting `word-break: break-word;`

Comment: I have tried `BreakWord` but break to new space at the beggining of problematic word in such a way that the justified one looks bad, I update the question with a photo of what happens

Comment: In your case you need both `word-break` and `break-all` which is not possible, you can do what suits best with possible scenario or may be anyone else have some solution..